# can't concatinate variable with string?

Tags: python, string

I'm going crazy as I learn python.

Here is a code fragment:

```
import re

class Spam:
    def egg(self, pat):
        print pat


attribute_pattern = r'(\s[a-z\-]+=".*?")*'

ok_uber_string = '<(us-patent-grant)'  r'(\s[a-z\-]+=".*?")*'   '>(.*?)(</\1>)'
bad_uber_string = '<(us-patent-grant)'  attribute_pattern   '>(.*?)(</\1>)'
pat = re.compile(bad_uber_string)
```

the line with bad_uber_string will not compile, get a SyntaxError: invalid syntax

This has to be a user error, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks
Pat

Comment: use `+` to concatenate `bad_uber_string = '<(us-patent-grant)' + attribute_pattern  + '>(.*?)(</\1>)'`

Comment: ok, thanks, but why does the "ok_uber_string" work without the +

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python will automatically glue string literals together:

```
some_string = "this will " "be one string"
```

In all other cases, you want to use the `+` operator to concatenate a value to a string:

```
bad_uber_string = '<(us-patent-grant)' + attribute_pattern + '>(.*?)(</\1>)'
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/65295

Answer (score 3):

Automatic concatenation only works for string **literals**.  To concatenate strings which aren't string literals, use the `+` operator

```
>>> "foo" "bar"
'foobar'
>>> bar = "bar"
>>> "foo" bar
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    "foo" bar
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> "foo" + bar
'foobar'
```

The reason for this is simple -- the automatic concatenation is done at parse time, not runtime:

```
>>> def foo():
...    return "foo" "bar"
... 
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('foobar') 
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

Due to the dynamic nature of python, it has no way of determining (in general) whether `bar` contains a string, or a float or any other user defined type until runtime.  And the special case where it is simple enough to determine ahead of time, isn't "special enough to break the rules" (`import this`).